# Convert coin to money in php

Tags: php

i'm trying to convert a coin to money like so:

2100 coins to 0,21 cents

21000 to 2,10 and so on..

I tried putting as 4 decimals but that's not what i wanted.

```
$var = 2100;

echo number_format($var, 4, '.', '');
```

Comment: Why 4 decimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devide it by 10000?

```
$var = 2100;

echo $var/10000;
```